# Read file line by line and print the first match in each line or "no_data" when nothing matches

Tags: linux, perl, shell, grep

I would like to read a text file line by line to search for a pattern; when the first match in a line is found, print it to a file and move to search for the pattern in the next line.

With my limited skills in shell I have tried the following; unfortunately, when there is no first pattern, it never prints `no_data` to the file `d.txt`.

```
while read u ; do
    echo "$u" | grep -o '[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{4\}  [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' |head -1 || echo "no_data" 
done < tmc.txt > d.txt
```

Note: the pattern I am trying to match is a date and time stamp in the format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`.

For instance, `$u` can be a string like this or even bigger with all sorts of garbage:

```
disk0/bcdackup_20160908_115716/d/.ER/ERORR_log_msnf_20160906_113039:10641:  Test Status:         Failed ;Test PL (some test) was started in execution mode.  09/06/2016  14:43:28.4954  Machine:msnf  (Rl888751, , ?.?, 1637) USER EVENT: TM-1102 DEFAULT  -- SYSTEM ERROR: TX-0003 INIT  Function Protocol Violation. Verification by TXXAxREQxConfig_destroy_config failed: 'engine_ptr != NULL' not TRUE  -- SYSTEM EVENT: ER-0FFF DEFAULT (linked to IH-154B) DEACTIVATE: IH-154b DEACTIVATE: IH-154b  -- SYSTEM EVENT: ER-0FFF DEFAULT (linked to IH-154C) DEACTIVATE: IH-154c DEACTIVATE: IH-154c  -- SYSTEM ERROR: WP-2631 CHANGEPARAMS  Error during processing of Finite State Machine Error starting perform_smooth_landing : event perform_smooth_landing not allowed in state {original_mc, actuator_system_enabled, service_off, not_homed} of state-machine WPLS.V1.2  -- SYSTEM ERROR: WP-2630 CHANGEPARAMS  Error during processing of F
```

Any shell utility such as grep, awk, sed, perl is fine by me.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to do `grep -o -E '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]{4}' < tmc.txt > d.txt`

Comment: Or `grep -o -E '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}'`

Comment: Ah, the reason your solution never prints "no_data" is that head never fails.  In this case, the `head` is useless and you can just remove it.  Another common solution is to add a `|grep .` after the last command in the pipe.

Comment: Hi William, if I use your suggestion of grep -o -E then for lines that contain multiple patterns of interest it will print multiple patterns

Comment: Remember that I am only interested in the first match for each line in that file

Comment: @DineshKumar: Add a flag `-m1` to it, `grep -om1E`

Comment: A shell loop for this is the wrong approach, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons why you should be writing an awk script instead of a shell script. [edit] your question to include a few lines of concise, testable sample input and expected output and someone will help you do this the right way.

Comment: Thanks Ed, for the information, shows that I have a lot to learn :)

Comment: Thank you all for sharing your expertise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
perl -nle 'print m{(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2})} ? $1 : "no_data"' < tmc.txt > d.txt
```

`-n` loops over lines in the input.

`-l` automatically chomps off newlines from the input and adds them to the output.

For each line we do a straightforward regex match with a capture group. If successful, we print the matched string, otherwise `no_data`.

Comment: This will most likely also mop the floor with the sed solution, performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

To do this directly with grep, you'd have to use some kind of variable-length negative look-behind to make sure that you're looking at the first date in the line. Apparently, Perl compatible regular expressions [would be able to do that](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=924643) with ["backtracking control verbs"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs), but a) I'm not sure if `grep -P` supports those and b) you also want to replace non-matching lines, which grep can't do anyway.

As an alternative to calling grep on every line, you could use sed:

```
sed -r '
    /([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/! { # On non-matching lines...
        s/.*/no_data/                               # Replace line with "no_data"
        b                                           # Skip to next line
    }
    s/(([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4} +[^ ]*).*/\1/ # Remove everything after first date
    s/.*(([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4})/\1/        # Remove everything before first date
' infile
```

For a version of `infile` using your sample line three times (first with both dates intact, then with the first date removed, then with both dates removed) the output is

```
$ sed -r '/([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/!{s/.*/no_data/;b};s/(([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4} +[^ ]*).*/\1/;s/.*(([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4})/\1/' infile
09/06/2016  14:43:28.4954
08/06/2016  18:53:28.4757
no_data
```

as expected.

The sed command first checks if the line contains a date; if not, the whole line is replaced by `no_data` and the rest of the commands is skipped. They wouldn't actually do anything, but this should make execution faster.

If the line *does* contain a date, two substitutions are performed: the first one removes everything after the first date, the second one everything before it. This *has* to happen in two steps, or the greedy matching would result in the *last* date on the line being printed.

---

Quick performance comparison for a 40 MB input file:

- Bash loop calling grep on each line: ~24 seconds
- Sed: ~4 seconds
- Perl: < 0.1 seconds

Comment: I did not try this solution yet, will provide an update soon